# How to reload UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have an application with multiple views. View1 shows has a tableview with a list of all the entries from a plist. View2 is a view which allows new entries to be added. When a new entry is added in View2, the plist is updated and View2 is removed from the superview (View2 is originally added as a subview on top of View1). What I want to do is reload the table in View1 before View2 is popped so that the updated table can be seen. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this all being done in 1 view controller?

Comment: no there are two view controllers

Answer (score 0):

in your second view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillDissappear {
  [super viewWillDissappear];
  [[self.previousViewController tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your tableView setup code in View1 to

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This way when you dismiss/pop View2 , View1 will reload the data for you.
Make sure you are actually closing view2
Your terminology is confusing me a bit, specifically

> View2 is removed from superview.

That is why I want to clarify that you will need to dismiss/pop View2 in order for View1 to gain focus and for   `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` to be called